# header for excel file save as

Tags: php, excel, header, save-as

im able to output an excel file by php and it opens correctly in excel. No problems there. When the user clicsk save as in Excel it comes with first option .txt How can i set the header so first option will .xls with save as.
Headers im using now :

```
$filename="jaar.xls";
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is $filename? If it's Something.xls then that's probably all you can do; mime & extension. I sometimes use the html-tables-to-excel shortcut but you can get a somewhat more native solution with the Spreadsheet Writer library in Pear

Comment: thats the content type i use, don't have any problems. You'll probably find your issue is browser specific too, not that that helps you

Comment: filename = jaar.xls
I wish it was that simple, i have added it to the source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution is to use phpexcel
http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/

if the xls file used is build with /t like a textfile it will be handled like a txt file by excel

Comment: As of May 2019 this project is dead. Find alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

If your name has spaces in it, you should try quoting it:

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='$filename'");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$filename);
```

This is enough to save as excel file